# How can I add two variables in a java subclass to pass as one variable to the superclass?

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass, superclass

I'm just learning Java, and I have a question. I'm not sure that I'm using the correct terminology, so please correct me if necessary. I'm curious if there is a better way to add the front and back claws to pass them to the Animal class.  This works as is, but I'm having trouble searching for what I am trying to do, which is making it hard to figure out if I'm doing it wrong.  Here's my subclass that I'm working with.

```
public class Bear extends Animal // This is a Bear class, it is a subclass of Animal.
{
  private int frontClaws; // This is an instance variable for front claws.
  private int backClaws;  // This is an instance variable for back claws.
  public Bear (String name, int fC, int bC) // This is the Bear constructor.
  {
    super (name, fC + bC); // This passes the name and the sum 
                           // of the claws to the Animal's constructor

    frontClaws = fC;  // not sure why this has to be done, 
                      // and frontClaws + backClaws can't be used directly. Because they are private?
    backClaws = bC;   // Same as confusion as above.
   }
    public void print()  // This calls the print method.
   {
    super.print();    // This calls the print method from 
                      // Animal and prints the args from Animal 
                      // as well as the args from Bear.
    System.out.println("- " + frontClaws + " Front Claws, and " + backClaws + " Back Claws.");
   }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

tc

Comment: I think you need to show the definition of `Animal` and what the parameters to its constructor means.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access fields before you call the superclass constructor - basically the *very first* thing that any constructor does is invoke a superclass constructor. The only thing you get to do is evaluate arguments to call that superclass constructor - in your case, that involves summing `fC` and `bC`.

Basically, assuming you *need* `Animal` to have the sum of `frontClaws` and `backClaws`, this looks like a reasonable implementation.

Answer (score 0):

**1.**

```
super (name, fC + bC); // This passes the name and the sum 
                           // of the claws to the Animal's constructor
```

is the first line of the constructor(as it must be), because 1st instruction in it is always a call to the super class constructor.

**This will throw error:**

```
public Bear (String name, int fC, int bC) // This is the Bear constructor.
  {
    frontClaws = fC;  
    backClaws = bC;  
    int totalClaws = fC + bC;
    super (name, totalClaws );
   }

error: call to super must be first statement in constructor
```

**2.**

```
frontClaws = fC;  // not sure why this has to be done, 
                      // and frontClaws + backClaws can't be used directly. Because they are private?
    backClaws = bC;   // Same as confusion as above.
```

**Because they are private?**

you are basically initializing these from the constructor so that they can be passed to the super-class' constructor. if that was not the case, then you had an option of their initialization through setter methods.